# Set operation problem on union of/ over

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For each $n \in \mathbb N$, let $A_n$ be the interval $[2^{-n}, 2^{1-n})$.
>
> Give a simple description of set $[0,1]\setminus \bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n$.

I don't quite understand this problem.

How do I evaluate $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n$ given the interval?

Any tips/ outline of steps would be appreciated.

Comment: To compute $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$, you can try to observe at first $\cup_{n=0}^NA_n$, then figure out a guess of the infinite union, then maybe prove it using some classical method.

Comment: Try drawing it on a line representing [0,1]. Note that $\mathbb{N}$ usually includes 0 these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could notice that $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}$ are seamlessly adjacent to each other with no intersection.

Notice that the definition of $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I}A_{\alpha}$ simply means the set of all element $x$, s.t. $x$ is in at least one $A_{\alpha}$. Therefore no limits of either $2^{-n}$ or $2^{1-n}$ are taken in terms of constructing the union of the sets. That being said, we cannot get $0$.

Thus we have $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n = (0, 2)$, here I assume $0 \in \mathbb N$

Thus $[0,1] \setminus \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n = \{0\}$

If we think $0 \notin \mathbb N$, we have $\{0,1\}$